# Is stalking users disallowed to some degree?

Tags: discussion

This morning I down voted a question that does not belong on this site in my opinion (as did a half-dozen others) using the very clear criteria for a down vote.

The user that was down voted dug up a 2 year old question of mine and attempted to initiate a dialog in the comments on this old question, trying to get me to explain why their question was down voted.  Overall the comment was somewhat harassing and I certainly don't intend to reply to it.

Is this type of behavior permitted here, or is it categorized under an existing rule?  If the former, I could see that being a problem since it may discourage users to down vote bad questions and answers, affecting the integrity of the information on this site.

The comment I'm referring to is below:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, such behaviour is not welcome, on Stack Exchange. You are not requested to leave a comment for each down-vote you cast, nor to explain why you down-voted.
That user is just trying to guess the users who down-vote him, but only the users who down-voted, and eventually Stack Exchange employees, can know who down-voted a post; elected moderators and normal users don't know the users who down-voted a post.

That user is not leaving any comments for his down-votes either, so he is the first not doing as he wants the others to do. If he keeps doing this, please flag the post where you read his comment with *in need of moderator intervention* and explains he left a comment like that. Moderators can see deleted comments, so he cannot deny he did it.